# Re-writing a a differential function

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

[image]

I don't understand the concept of this... how do I derive a an equation written in terms of a function? How do I differentiate f(function inside) ...?

Comment: Have you seen the chain rule before?

Comment: yes... but i am a bit weak in the theory. chain rule is for composite function such as f(g(x)) so you derive g(x) and multiply by the derivative of the whole thing.. 

so in this case:

4cos(4x) * f'(sin(4x)) ... is that it?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. In general, when two functions are being composed, you should try the chain rule first.

Comment: but isnt it f'(sin(4x)) just 4cos(4x)....

Comment: No. Here, $f$ is an arbitrary differentiable function. We don't know anything else about $f$, so we cannot simplify $f'(\sin(4x))$ any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: the chain rules claims that:

$$ \frac{\partial f(\square)}{\partial x} =  \frac{\mathrm{d} f(\square)}{\mathrm{d} \square}  \, \frac{\partial \square}{\partial x}. $$ It is common to write $\frac{\mathrm{d} f(\square)}{\mathrm{d} \square}$ as $f'(\square)$.

Comment: yes i think i understand now! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good day. I would say that

$\frac{d f(\sin 4x)}{d x}=\frac{d f(\sin 4x)}{d(\sin 4x)}\cdot \frac{d(\sin4x)}{dx}=4\cos 4x\cdot f'(\sin4x)$

Edit:Correction of errors

Comment: Your $f'(x)$ should be $f'(\sin(4x))$

Comment: @Thomas Credeur: Thanks for the warning.